# View does not handle click events after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, onclick, screen, orientation, handle

I have one weird issue. I have developed application (Android 1.5) which does not recreates itself on changing screen orientation (android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden") and do nothing on configChange method (just to forbid recreating activity), but some of my special views lost possibility to handle onClick events, futhermore they are still available for focus and for activating them via Enter key pressing, but not for clicks. And one more, onclick functionality is being restored when I change orientation back. You can easyly reproduce this issue on Quattro banner (http://www.quattrowireless.com/about_quattro/press_releases_detail/quattro_launches_new_android_ad_kit/%20).

Comment: If you want answers, I suggest you take the time to a) split this into separate questions b) proofread and reformulate, preferably with some attention to where sentences and paragraphs should end c) provide code examples of what isn't working right now.

Comment: About source code, download Snake Quattor Test application. Insert android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" into manifest. Start test Snake application and just change screen orientation. I did not add anything into this test application but it illustrates my issue.